Queue implemented by linked list with O(n) time complexity
As the title says, I want to implement a queue using a linked list. However, when I try to implement enqueue or dequeue, I have to traverse the linked list to get the last element, which has a time complexity of O(n). On the other hand, using an array to implement the queue can achieve O(1) time complexity. Is there any approach that allows me to implement these operations with O(1) time complexity, perhaps by using another pointer or something similar?
Can I get the last element with a time complexity of O(1) in a linked list?
Looking forward to your answer!

Keep the pointer (reference or whatever your language has) to the last element in a variable, then you can get the last element in O(1). It's perfectly possible, go for it.

I use C program language , where I should put the pointer in ?
in the struct or other place? this is the key. can you give me your point?

You are presumably keeping the pointer to the first element somewhere. Put the other pointer close to it so it's not lonely.

If you cannot make it work, then please edit your question and add the minimal code to reproduce the issue.

Will you still post your code or is your question obsolete?

I implemented it by using a struct like
struct queue{
ptr front;
ptr rear;
}
}

Ok so question can be closed.

Consider a doubly linked list using a single node as a sentinel node, which does not store data but points to the head and the tail of your list, making the list circular. By maintaining a reference to the sentinel node, your enqueue function can add new elements directly after the tail, and your dequeue function can remove elements directly from the head. This is a neat implementation where the sentinel node simplifies the boundary conditions, and allows for constant time for both operations.

This is how Visual Studio implements C++ std::list, except that its sentinel node is the same as the std::list nodes and sets data to zero or null.

thank you so much , it looks like that the way of implement queue by array . it also use a circular array to implement the queue.

Cool :) GeeksForGeeks has a detailed article with an implementation. If you found this useful, consider accepting the answer :)
